# High Siera- clicking mouse obscures Cursor tip hotspot with yellow

Tags: macos, mouse, cursor

I have just updated to Mac High Siera. 
Now, on clicking the mouse, the cursor hotspot area is temporarily obscured by non-translucent yellow. How can I change/stop this?

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot?  If that's not feasible can you take a picture/video with your phone?  It's very difficult to visualize what you're describing.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to attach a photo I have taken to this comment....

Comment: ***Attach the photo by editing  the original question***